# Static Vs. Dynamic Optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I am beginner to optimization and my question is fundamental. We all know that Static optimization means the design variables/objective function does not vary with respect to time. Dynamic optimization means the design variables vary with time. I need help in organizing the below algorithms/concepts into static and dynamic optimization categories.

1. Ordinary calculus
2. Dynamic Programming
3. Convex Optimization
4. Tabu Search
5. Lagrange multiplier
6. Genetic Algorithm
7. Calculus of Variations
8. Simulated Annealing
9. Linear/Non-Linear Programming
10. Particle Swarm Optimization
11. Ant Colony Optimization
12. First and Second Order Algorithms

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your statement is not correct. In dynamic optimization you search for a path or functin minimizing the optimization problem, i.e. an element of a function space (infinite dimensional). In static optimization you search for a parameter vector (an element of a finite dimensional space, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$). Thus, the nature of the optimization problems are completely different.